# JS - saber o id do botão clicado para usar em uma função

Tags: javascript

Criei uma tabela com uma série de botões, 100 ao todo, e cada botão recebeu um id que é gerado automaticamente. Quero saber como pegar o id do botão que foi clicado, pois tenho a intenção de mudar a cor dele. Não sei programar em JS, mas tenho que fazer um trabalho, o que fiz até agr foi através de pesquisas.

```js
const cellArray = []
let cellWidth = 10
let cellHeight = 10

function start() {
    createCellsDataStructure()
    renderCells()
}

function createCellsDataStructure() {
    const numberOfCells = cellWidth * cellHeight

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++) {
        cellArray[i] = 0
    }
}

function cellsProgation() {

}

function changeColor(){
    
}

function renderCells() {
    let html = '<table cellpadding=0 cellsapcing=0>'
    for (let row = 0; row < cellHeight; row++) {
        html += '<tr>'
        
        for (let column = 0; column < cellWidth; column++) {
            const cellIndex = column + (cellWidth * row)
            html += '<td class="cell-index">'
            html += `<button id="cell-index-${cellIndex}" onClick="changeColor()"></button>`
            html += '</td>'
        }

        html += '</tr>'
    }
    html += '</table>'

    document.querySelector('#cellBlock').innerHTML = html
}


start()
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fundamento de Sistemas</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: center;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            position: relative;
        }

        button {
            font-size: 10px;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
            color: #999;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="cellBlock"></div>
    <script src="constructor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quero que cada mude sua cor quando for clicado, a intenção é fazer um automato celular, se puderem dar dicas de como fazer será de grande ajuda.

Comment: Normalmente eu uso jquery, dou uma classe aos botoes, e uso o this pra mudar a cor do botao

Comment: Uma forma é passar `this` na função: `onClick="changeColor(this)"`, e na função fazer assim: `changeColor(elemento){ var id = elemento.id; }`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!!!